# Why is Python 3 not available in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, incompatibility

This is the [changelog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2011/03/pycharm-1-2-released-with-a-new-academic-license-type/) of version 1.2 of PyCharm and they say it is compatible with Python 3.2. Now version 1.5.4 say that it's working until Python 3.1.

I'm running the trial version on Mac, and the program it's using 2.6 python-default framework and I can't get python 3.2 one (I can't find it in Python.framework). I'm working on a python3k project and I don't want to translate it to v2 nor install python 3.1.

Thanks for the patience, sorry for bad english.

Comment: post a bug report on their website. Not here

Comment: @JBernardo  it is not a PyCharm bug more a bad title considering the real issue - and the OP not understanding how the tools he uses fit together.

Answer (score 3):

Pycharm does not include python so you need to get it in another fashion.

OSX only includes a python from the 2.x series so you need to install a python from the 3.x series

there are various ways of doing this

1) Install from [python.org](http://python.org/download/releases/3.2.2/) - thus requires nothing else.

2) Install from a package manager e.g. macports, fink, homebrew - this makes it easier if you have complex C library dependencies